# How to join 2 tables and and get matching outputs?

Tags: sql, join, select

I am learning sql at the moment.
For example I have two tables: `book` and `author`.

Table book: `title` varchar, `releaseDate` date, `author_id` int (foreignkey)

Author: `id` int, `name` varchar

How would I get the names of the books where the authors' name is "King"?

I thought about doing it like this:

```
Select book.title
FROM book JOIN author 
ON book.author_id = author.id AND author.name = 'King'
```

Is this the right approach? Or is it wrong?

Maybe someone with more knowledge can help me.
Thank you

Comment: only if the name is exactly like King. so if the Name was Stephen King would get no results you would use `LIKE '%King%'`

Comment: @nbk ok. But it would be right, If I am just looking for 'King'?

Comment: @zeppal if the name conatians only King in it yes, but usually we define name with all names not only surname